# Parsing file into nested dictionary

Tags: elixir

I have a config file that I would like to read with the following format

```
[key_1]
inner_key_1 inner_entry_1
inner_key_2 inner_entry_2
inner_key_3 inner_entry_3
inner_key_4 inner_entry_4
[key_2]
inner_key_5 inner_entry_5
inner_key_6 inner_entry_6
inner_key_7 inner_entry_7
inner_key_8 inner_entry_8
```

Which would then be mapped into a nested Elixir dictionary like such.

```
%{key_1 => %{inner_key_1 => inner_entry_1, ... }, key_2 => %{inner_key_5 => inner_entry_5,...}}
```

I am having trouble conceptualizing how to do this with Elixir and functional programming. I have tried using the Stream library in order to achieve this but have had no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple solution could look similar to this:

```
def read_config(file) do
  file
  |> File.stream!()
  |> Stream.map(&String.trim/1)
  |> Enum.reduce({%{}, nil}, &read_config/2)
  |> elem(0)
end

defp read_config("[" <> key, {acc, _top_key}) do
  key = String.trim_trailing(key, "]")
  {Map.put(acc, key, %{}), key}
end
defp read_config(key_value, {acc, top_key}) do
  [key, value] = String.split(key_value, " ")
  {put_in(acc, [top_key, key], value), top_key}
end
```

When translating an imperative loop into a functional style, you'd most often use a reduce. The next step is to identify all the state that you need during each iteration - in this case, we need the "result so far" and the current top-level key - this is similar to what you'd use in an imperative solution as mutable variables outside of the loop.

Comment: Why is something like `"[" <> key <> "]"` not allowed, what is the reason for prohibiting the `<>` operator from being used like so.

Comment: Only the last part of a binary match can omit the size. `"foo" <> bar` syntax is the same as `<<"foo", bar::binary>>`, so this limitation applies here as well. In a way, it's a limitation only of the current implementation and could be lifted with some work in Erlang itself.